# su processes spawning with high CPU (Debian 9)

Tags: debian, su, top, pid

I am running a VM on Google Cloud with Debian 9. I should be the only user with access to the VM.

Every so often the Web application I am running (phpbb) becomes very slow.

When I log into to look at `top`, I see that there are su processes running taking 99% of the CPU. I kill one, and another one spawns. I kill four, and it ends for while. Within about a day, the same thing starts again.

If I check the command that is being run, it tells me:

```
 su nobody -s /bin/sh -c false
```

I have no idea what is spawning these commands or what their purpose might be. Any help in terms of how to figure out would be greatly appreciated.

(In case it might be relevant, `sudo su` is very slow for reasons I do not understand: it takes several minutes before responding. But I do not use it in general.)

Comment: `false` itself should exit in shorter than a blink anyway (as it does nothing but exit with code 1), so the fact that `su` stalls is mostly relevant. (Have you tried / tested `sudo -i` / `sudo -s` btw?) In any case, the command `su nobody -s /bin/sh -c false` looks suspicious to me; what would be the reason to run `false` as a specific / another user anyway?

Comment: `sudo -s` works without problem, just `sudo su` is very slow or sometimes does not work at all. The command is probably eating so much CPU because of some issue with `su`, not with false. No clue what is invoking the `su` command, but would love to know or to block it. Maybe there is even a way to disable the `su` command or something?

Comment: See if `pstree` / `systemctl status -- -.slice` gives you any clue

Comment: Will try that the next time the process pops up, thanks!

Comment: Btw, you can consider running a script of an infinite loop that e.g. runs `pgrep -f 'su nobody -s /bin/sh -c false'` every 30s and captures the output of those commands to files if it returns something (and exits).

Comment: I think I found a possible reason why it was slow. Google Cloud Platform had added hundreds of thousands of duplicate lines to the `/etc/pam.d/su` file. Removing these seems to have solved the `su` performance issues, though not sure what is spawning these particular `su` commands.

Comment: Well, maybe you should have leave the file untouched until you grab what's spawning the command